# VBA - Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed

Tags: vba, excel

Excuse me if you guys see this question again. However, I have searched for similar topics in this site but can't figure out my problem.

I have a VBA code snipet with a line throwing back an error:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range: ", "Select range", Type:=8)

MsgBox (Range("rng").Rows.Count)

End Sub
```

My intention is to prompt user to select a range and to count number of rows in that range.

If I pre-define the name range "rng" instead of selecting range in run-time like the code below, it will return the number of rows without errors.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range

MsgBox (Range("rng").Rows.Count)

End Sub
```

Could someone please tell me the problem with the range selected by user so that it can't return number of rows? Doesn't the "rng" range defined by user have a "Rows" property?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could use an InputBox that way. In my usual scripts I try to have everything done automatically, but when automatic doesn't work, this could come handy.

Comment: @Inarion thanks, I was managing to make the macro as user friendly as possible and I found that useful method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
MsgBox (Range("rng").Rows.Count)
```

To:

```
MsgBox rng.Rows.Count
```

Answer (score 2):

rng is already a valid range and it has it's own Rows propery which you can access like this...

Also, consider to handle the case if user doesn't select any range and hit Cancel on InputBox.

```
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range: ", "Select range", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng.Rows.Count
```

Comment: I was focusing on fixing the error and forget to handle that exception. Thank for your advice.